# Target not showing in CLion run configurations

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I have a C++ project in CLion and everything has been working well.
Today I wanted to add a new target, let us call it `emst`, which is nothing but this https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/BGL_triangulation_2_2emst_8cpp-example.html.
I do the usual thing, which had always worked for me:
1) create a folder, say "helper"
2) put the file "emst.cpp" into it
3) create a CMakeLists.txt with the following contents:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(emst emst.cpp)
target_link_libraries(emst
        PRIVATE sdsl)
target_compile_options(emst BEFORE PUBLIC -mcmodel=large PRIVATE -pg -g -O2)
```

Never mind stuff like `sdsl` -- it is a library installed on my system, and I have no problem with the above set-up for all the other code in the project.
Overall, the structure looks like this:
[image]

Now, the target `emst` does not show up among the targets of `CLion`.
How could that be? I remember someone suggesting at SE to `Mark directory as Source` or `as Library`, but neither of these worked for me.
What am I missing?
I had the exact same setup for all the other `cpp`-targets in my project, and it worked hitherto fine.

It also says

> Cannot compile file 'emst.cpp'. Cannot find run configuration for this
>   file

EDIT:
from the icons you can see that `CMakeLists.txt` is treated as a text-file only, in the above directory:
[image]